# Индексировать spa

Tags: seo, ajax

Сайт состоит из областей, обновляемых при помощи ajax. Как создать условия для того, чтобы поисковые роботы видели сайт такими, каким видят его пользователи ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, [почитайте](http://webmaster.ya.ru/13754), что пишет Яндекс по этому поводу.

Comment: Как создаются url с #tags ?